# Can't login to SharePoint 2013 site on server machine?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on SharePoint 2013 server on premise. Surprisingly, I am not able to log in at SharePoint 2013 site on server side, when it is allowing me to log in on the same site with the same credentials on local machine.

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Adding backhostConnectionNames should help.

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
3. Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
4. Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click  Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local  computer, and then click OK.

I don't remember if IIS reset is necessary.